# É possível customizar o diretório do Apache?

Tags: html, css, apache

É possível customizar o diretório do Apache onde é listado os arquivos enviados para o servidor?

Comment: Você quer trocar o diretório de onde o apache lê os arquivos, ou trocar a aparência da listagem/índice do conteúdo?

Comment: @bfavaretto Exatamente seria isto: alterar a aparência da listagem dos conteúdos.

Answer (score 1):

Alterando no httpd.conf as informações abaixo o apache começa a listar o conteudo da pasta root.

```
<directory /diretorio/root/apache>
    Options +Indexes
</directory>
```